# How to format negative amounts with Joda Money?

Tags: java, joda-money

I'd like to format negative amounts with minus sign **before** currency symbol, i. e:

Given input value: `-123.45`

I want the output to be: `-$123.45`.

Is there any way to acomplish it with Joda Money?

Here's what I tried:

```
Money money = Money.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, -123.45);
MoneyFormatter formatter = new MoneyFormatterBuilder()
                 .appendCurrencySymbolLocalized()
                 .appendAmountLocalized()
                 .toFormatter(Locale.US);
String formatted = formatter.print(money);
```

But that gives me: `$-123.45`

Comment: Do you have code that you have tested? Joda Money does have methods like `isNegative()` so I assume that you are able to set it to be negative.

Comment: Please put that into the main post, not into the comments.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know it would look so bad.

Comment: Are you able to call `.appendLiteral("-");` before `.appendCurrencySymbolLocalized();`? If so, I'd say to have two formatters, one for negative, and one for positive and use an if-test to check if it is negative or not.

Comment: So why bother with Joda if in the end I have to implement formatting on my own?

Comment: You already use your own formatting...? That's what `MoneyFormatter` is doing. You would just be appending a negative sign in front of the rest of that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joda Money 0.11 (released after your question was asked) added [`appendSigned`](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/apidocs/org/joda/money/format/MoneyFormatterBuilder.html#appendSigned-org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter-org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter-) to the formatter, which allows you to specify different formatters for negative, zero, and positive numbers. This will allow you to specify your own custom format for each case.